# Acrobat X Custom Action to Save PDF as JPG (not export all images)

Tags: adobe-indesign, adobe-acrobat, adobe-bridge

Can I use Acrobat X Pro to batch process hundreds of multipage PDFs to JPGs?

[This question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1221/best-way-to-convert-multipage-pdf-to-separate-jpgs) is very similar to what I am after but I am wondering if there is a way to do it in Acrobat X Pro. I have asked on superuser.com and the adobe forums and have received no conclusive answers. The previously linked question brought me here.

I have several hundred pdfs. Some were originally composed from Tiffs and others JPGs. I'd like to convert them all to JPGs. Ideally I would do it on the command line.

The following:

`convert document.pdf document.jpg`

works really well, when the source material was originally a JPG, but if it was originally a TIFF not so well. I have found a *"ghostscript"* that can handle the conversion from tiff, but not reliably. Plus, I have no real way to determine what the PDF was composed of originally.

I am turning to MS Windows and Acrobat X Pro to handle my troubles. I have been a linux user for the past five or so years, so my familiarity with adobe products is rusty. Acrobat X can easily save a multi-page PDF to a JPG, and they look great regardless of if the origin files.

However, I see no clear way to do this as a batch (aka: "Action"). I see an action to export all the images in a document, and for some reason it gives me three images from a page. with only one of the three being useable. But is there a way to specify a custom Action that simply saves the PDF as JPGs?

Why not as of much importance, is there also a way to specify proper padding? For example, when you manually save a 9 page document to JPGs it appends

- _Page_1.jpg
- _Page_2.jpg
- etc.

A 900 page document will list page 1 as "_Page_001.jpg".

Perferablly it would be nice to always have "%04d", or "_Page_0001.jpg".

Note: I've include other Adobe Tags as I am have many products in the CS 5.5 suite to work with — yes I know its older, and no I don't know all of the ones I have.

Comment: Are all just tiffs and jpegs wrapped in a PDF, or is there any vector data within the PDFs? Could you provide a sample of one or two?

Comment: 1. Yes all are either Tiffs or Jpgs. 2. Sorry, No I am unable to provide a sample.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Best way to convert multipage pdf to separate jpg's](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1221/best-way-to-convert-multipage-pdf-to-separate-jpgs). There are quite a few solutions provided there, would any of them work for you?

Comment: @John, It differs from my question. If you had of read my question you would see I discus (and link) to that question immediately after my TL;DR. Thanks for looking for a duplicate. It is one of the items that make the stackexchange community great.

Comment: I'm an idiot that can't read, apparently. One more question: could you elaborate on "it gives me three images from a page. with only one of the three being useable"? What makes them unusable?

Comment: @John, fair question. This is where providing a sample would be incredibly useful. Sadly, I am unable to--licensing issues. The best I can describe it are the other images are either faded to such a low opacity, or has strange artifacts of the page. This is from the Export All Images on a Page option. If I hit file>save>image it works perfectly.

Comment: I can write you an applescript droplet that could export all images within a pdf file if you're on a mac?

Comment: @mousebat, sorry I was actually able to solve this problem. I wish I had remembered about this question, as at this point I forget the exact option, but I was able to set it all up inside Acrobat. If someone is in dire need of answer to this same question drop me a line I can probably remember what I did exactly.

Comment: @matchew you really should post the solution here as many users (such as myself) won't be emailing you for the solution as it isn't needed per se... but would like to know "what" you did to solve it in case the need for it arises later.

Comment: @Phlume I agree, the problem being is that this all happened a considerable time ago. I wish I could remember the solution, but I do not. I do recall it being possible from Acrobat. In general I am doing this with imagemagick in linux when I find myself needing to convert PDF to JPG

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of documenting this, here's how I would go about it.

To create the files:

- From within Acrobat X or XI, open the Actions Wizard and choose "Create New Action"
- In the `Files to be Processed` panel, either choose "Add Files..." under `Default option:` or choose them explicitly by clicking the document or folder (processes all documents in the specified folder) icon
- In `Choose tools to add:` open `Save & Export`, choose "Export All Images As JPEG" and add it to the action.
- Under "Specify Settings," either leave `Prompt User` selected or explicitly set up the export options.
- Save and name the Action
- Run the Action

An alternative page-at-a-time approach is to use `Save` rather than `Export All Images...` and choose an image format in the Save settings.

To handle the file naming problem:

- Open the folder with the saved images in Bridge
- Ctl-A/Cmd-A to select all
- Select `Tools < Batch Rename...`
- Set up the renaming criteria as required and click `Rename`

As an additional note, I would be more likely to save as PNG or TIFF, then use Bridge's Image Processor (under `Tools > Photoshop`) to handle the jpeg conversion, for a better result than working from Acrobat directly.